# Any known limitations to special characters in shortcut pathname and "Run as Administrator"?

Tags: windows, special-characters, runas, shortcut-file

I'm working on a project that creates Windows shortcuts to batch files, and have been testing special characters in the pathname to the batch script.  One problem that has me stumped is that a pathname will work when the shortcut is invoked normally, but if "Run as Administrator" is used, it does not work.

For example, if the pathname to the shortcut is "`C:\Program Files\myapp )]}@#$_-=+'.{[(\bin\hello.bat`", I can run it fine when I click on the shortcut.  When I select "Run as Administrator" it does not work.  The shortcut Target value does have double quotes around the pathname.

I can invoke the above pathname with no problems from the Command Prompt, either running as Administrator or as a regular user.

I put in a prompt at the beginning of the batch script to determine if the batch script itself fails, but it does not.  When run-as is used, it appears the script is never launched.

My guess there is something in how Windows (7) performs the run-as operation that is getting tripped up by one (or more) of the special characters in the pathname.  Is there any known/documented pathname characters limitations of using run-as (with batch scripts[?])?

**UPDATE:**
After some testing, I discovered that it is the '`@`' character that screws things up.  When I run a test with that character not present, the run-as operation succeeds.  Not sure what is special about that character wrt run-as.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10, if a .cmd file's name contains **@** or **^** or **&** , the file cannot be run as an administrator. If a .cmd file's parent folder's name contains **@** or **^** or **&** , the file cannot be run as an administrator even if the file's name does not contain **@** or **^** or **&**. 

Ironically, if a .cmd file's name is:
 **㊣〇●♥★✺㊥❤️** 

the file can be run as an administrator.